# Notifications to followers of a question about its status updates (closed / open)

Tags: feature-request, closing, notifications, re-open, follow-post

In my opinion, one of the most important functions of following a question should be to notify users its status updates. For example, say I encountered a question in the close vote review queue that I think doesn't warrant a closure. Although I can vote to leave it open, it is very likely that the question has already accrued 3-4 close votes leaving it on the verge of getting closed. If following a question sends notification to users about its status updates, I can vote to reopen the question as soon as it gets closed, and vice versa. Could this suggestion be implemented?

Comment: This post on [meta.se] is marked  [meta-tag:status-planned]: [Send authors an inbox message if their question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842). It is about notifying the OP - so it is different from your request. Still, following the post give notifications similar to the ones that are sent to the OP.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the link. I completely missed the fact that even the OP does not receive notifications about their own question. Hope they implement it soon!

Comment: I see that yo have offered a bounty on the question about notifications to the OP: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/93842/revisions https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/93842/timeline - we'll see whether this will lead to some response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For post reopening:

- Post owners receive an inbox notification when their closed question is reopened. See [Are users notified when their questions are reopened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230959#336960).
- Post followers receive an inbox notification when a closed question they follow is reopened. See [How can I get a notification when someone else's question is reopened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351104).

#### For post closure:

See [“Question closed” notifications experiment results and graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356742) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

> The following is now live, network wide:
>
> - Post owner inbox notifications when their question is closed
> - Post follower inbox notifications when a question that they follow is closed
> - No notifications are sent to:
>
>   - Anyone when the question is closed due to being migrated to another site (this has its own notification)
>   - The OP or any follower who cast the last vote for closing the question (including when a question author self-dupes their own question)

I believe email notifications also sent to post owners (but [I'm not sure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396755) whether they are also sent to post followers) one day after the post is closed.

> This excludes posts where the post owner has already edited the post, where the post is deleted or reopened, or where the post owner has indicated that they do not want to receive emails of this nature.