# Favoriting / bookmarking a question while working the Close Queue?

Tags: bug, review, closing, bookmarks

Is there a way to favorite / bookmark when you encounter it in the Close Queue? I didn't see the little bookmark icon under the vote count widget (but then I frequently miss elements in the math.se interface). I was using the mobile site on Firefox for Android, if that makes a difference.

Also, maybe there was a better way than bookmarking to achieve my goal, so I'll describe that too. The question had four comments, the last of which offered a dupe, and there was one answer, by a user who I tend to think of as someone will quickly write up an answer even on a likely dupe. So it's understandable that there were 4 votes to close as a duplicate. But I went ahead and read the offered dupe and the answer, and the dupe only sort of addressed the question, while the posted answer was very thorough and addressed both components of the question. So my thought was "I'll bet this gets closed. I should bookmark it and come back later and suggest a re-open". But there was no bookmark icon! Hence this post.

Comment: My searches on [metase] did not turn up any related posts. It may be worth posting a feature request there :) (And, perhaps the [meta-tag:support] tag is more appropriate here?)

Comment: The review queues prevent a lot of actions, depending on the queue.  The workaround, of course, is to open the relevant post, in a new tap (click on title of what you are reviewing), and bookmark from their.  I've raised the issue, e.g., of not being able to flag mods when a persistent user is vandalizing posts, (separate from the audits).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  This isn't the first expressed concern about lack of tools available in the review queue.  While I appreciate your exuberance in helping out on meta, and in chats, you've not yet a year's experience on this site.  Review queues typically do not have available tools with which we are familiar with; I agree they ought to have mechanisms to alert mods about abuse on the site, etc.  But this issue is not new, but perhaps it is to you.

Comment: Jonathon, I wrote a typo in my first comment.  Instead of "tap" I meant *"tab"

Comment: Thanks, @amWhy. Good overview and good workaround. I'm still getting used to the mobile interface, so thought i might be missing something.  I don't know if you want to wait for others to chime in, but i think your comment could be an answer that finishes this post?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  Let's give it a bit more time.  But I'll be happy to answer, if there's little further input.  But I'd be happy to answer now, if you'd prefer.

Comment: @amWhy - No rush. Turn it into an answer when you think there's been enough time for others to give any input, and I'll accept it then.

Comment: Although the bookmark button is missing, you could follow the post. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZyed.png); see also Meta.SE post [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Since you've mentioned [meta.se], I'll add a link to this feature request: [Can't favorite a question under beta review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147630). However, that one is from 2012 and it did not get much attention (no comments, a few votes, two edits), less than 50 views.

Comment: Ooh, good idea @CalvinKhor. I've never followed questions before, this looks like a good use of it. I wasn't sure getting closed was a notification triggering event, but that's what the first comment on that announcement seems to indicate.

Comment: Despite the fact that we found an older feature request similar to the issue, I think it still might be reasonable to make a new post on [meta.se] - as @TheAmplitwist suggested. (The site changed a lot since 2012 - so probably the feature request which was posted such a long time ago isn't really relevant now.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC To verify the post I linked, I followed a question from the close votes queue and waited, then indeed [got notified when it was closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qCKd.png). I also [got a notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl7uk.png) for a post that was reopened when I followed from the reopen queue. When I followed and then voted to close, I didn't get a notification (It seems I was the last close voter; perhaps I was too quick and the system didn't update my list of followed posts yet)

Comment: @CalvinKhor In case it helps, I compiled the information I found regarding notifications sent to followers about closure/reopening in an [answer to 'Notifications to followers of a question about its status updates (closed / open)'](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33562/915354).

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinKhor. My general impression is that you don't get notified about your own actions, which would explain your second test case.

Comment: A recent related feature request on Meta SE: [Saving posts while reviewing in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383737)